# Unable to create SparkContext object using Apache Spark 2.2 version

Tags: scala, apache-spark, windows-7

I use MS Windows 7.

Initially, I tried one program using scala in Spark 1.6 and it worked fine (where I am getting SparkContext object as sc automatically).

When I tried Spark 2.2, I am not getting `sc` automatically so I created one by doing the following steps:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext  
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf  
val sc = new SparkConf().setAppName("myname").setMaster("mast")  
new SparkContext(sc)
```

Now when I am trying to execute below parallelize method it gives me one error:

```
val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  
val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
```

Error:

```
Value parallelize is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```

I followed these steps using official documentation only. So can anybody explain me where I went wrong? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I understand from _"where I am getting SparkContext object as sc automatically"_ that you use `spark-shell`, don't you? Have you defined `HADOOP_HOME` and/or saved `winutils.exe` in `$HADOOP_HOME/bin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **spark-shell** doesn't show this line on start:

> Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-XXX).

Run

```
val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Thanks but it throws one error as i have already mentioned in below answer's comments

Comment: Which version of spark-shell are you using?

Comment: Read the awnser and it's important to try it in a new spark-shell session

Comment: i am not getting this line. SparkContext available as sc. Even i am getting error on sqlContext

Comment: Please post your spar-shell initialization messages

Comment: Did you try this val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()?

Comment: yeah i ll update that one but can you explain me how this way of creating sparkcontext object is different from the way which i have posted. Can you explain me in layman terms ? it would be very helpful

Comment: sparks-shell currently has a sparkContext but you don't have it propertly assigned to variable. If you  try inside spark-shell to create a new SparkContext on your own way jvm shows an error saying that currently exists a SparkContext. SparkContext.getOrCreate () function manage the situation and if exists a SparkContext return it, otherwise create a new one and return it.

Comment: It answers your doubts about sparkContext in sparkShell? If so, remember to approve the answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you created `sc` of type `SparkConfig` not `SparkContext` (both have the same initials).

---

For using parallelize method in Spark 2.0 version or any other version, `sc` should be `SparkContext` and not `SparkConf`. The correct code should be like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext  
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf  
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myname").setMaster("mast")  
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  
val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
```

This will give you the desired result.

Comment: should i pass sparkConf in new SparkContext() instead of sc?

Comment: Oops! My mistake. Yes, you should pass `sparkConf` in `new SparkContext` instead of `sc`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: it throws one error that only one sparkcontext object should be running in jvm. How can i avoid this ?

Comment: Are you using `spark-shell`?

Comment: Then you don't need to create `sc` there. It is already created for you. `Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.1.13:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1514126801063).
Spark session available as 'spark'.`

Comment: so in this case what should be my code ?. I tried last two lines only but still getting that error

Comment: Simple - `val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  
val distData = sc.parallelize(data)`

Comment: <console>:21: error: not found: value sc
       val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
                      ^

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer to use `SparkSession` as it is the the entry point for Spark from version 2. You could try something like :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder.
    master("local")
    .appName("spark session example")
    .getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext
val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
```

[image: This is what I tried in Databricks]

Comment: nope. It doesnt work. it throws error on getorcreate method. As far as i remember you posted some comment above but you deleted it. I dont know why. If that concept is correct then why dont you post it again ??

Comment: Edited and tested in Databricks: was using `sparkSession` variable to get the `SparkSession` and using `spark` in getting `sparkContext`, edited to `spark` variable in both places. This was a mistake from my end. Sorry for that.  Now, this code  will work if you are using `Spark 2`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but it still throws an error. It gives a long error which can't be posted here

Comment: This is very basic code. Are you able to create `SparkSession` ? If you are running in `spark-shell` ,the `SparkSession` would be available as `spark`.(In `version 2`).  Check by using `spark.version`.

Comment: It throws this error : 
C:\Users\hp>spark.version
'spark.version' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: then try `sc.version`

Comment: which ide or any tool you are using for spark ??

Comment: I would suggest you to update your question with exact screenshot of the `spark-shell`. I guess `sparkContext` variable and `SparkSession` has not been created. What is the version number you are getting when starting `spark-shell` ?

Comment: 2.2 is my version and I am getting the same error when i tried your above code. I dont know why its not working on my system

Comment: In `version 2` when initialising `spark-shell`, `SparkSession` would be available to you as `spark`.

Comment: how to verify this ?? because i can't see any messages . I was able to see in cloudera 1.6 version where sc was available automatically

Comment: i am getting this error when i am starting spark shell : <console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/

Comment: Either you have some problem with your `spark` installation or you didn't set up `spark` properly. In normal case, `spark-shell` will create `SparkSession` for you. You could try [Databricks](https://community.cloud.databricks.com/) if you just learn and test. Hope it make sense.

Comment: yes i will try that and meanwhile i am replacing 2.2.0 version with 2.2.1 version. lets c and can you help me with that dataframe problem on which you have already commented

Comment: Yes i replaced my version with 2.2.1 and the problem is solved.

Comment: Please update your question with the way you solved. It would help others. Thanks

Comment: i have posted an answer for the same

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with `2.2.0 version` of Apache Spark. I replaced it with `2.2.1 version` which is the latest one and i am able to get `sc` and `spark` variables automatically when I start `spark-shell` via `cmd` in `windows 7`. I hope it will help someone.
I executed below code which creates rdd and it works perfectly. No need to import any packages.

```
val dataOne=sc.parallelize(1 to 10)
dataOne.collect(); //Will print 1 to 10 numbers in array
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code shud like this

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local[*]")
conf.setAppName("myname")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

NOTE: master url should be local[*]